# Deny view definition at DB level and symmetric keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions

I don't want a restricted database role to be able to view table and stored procedure definitions and code.

So I do

```
deny view definition to some_db_role
```

It does appear though that this is not capable of being overridden.

```
grant view definition on dbo.some_proc to some_db_role
```

seems to have no effect.

**Worse**

```
grant view definition, references on symmetric key::some_key to some_db_role
```

seems to have no effect. Basically if you deny view definition at the db level then symmetric keys are unusable by that role\user.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to grant rights to objects that override the rights of the db level deny?

Answer (score 2):

From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667986.aspx#Anchor_2):

> any permission denial overrides all grants

The implication is that when you `DENY` permissions to an object those permissions override any `GRANTed` permissions applicable to that object.

Having said that, you don't need to explicitly deny "view definition" permissions on procedures and other code.  If you don't grant `VIEW DEFINITION` the definitions are not visible, even if the code can be executed.  Tables work slightly differently; you'll need to `deny view definition` to any tables the role has `SELECT` rights on.

You can test this using the code below.

Create a test database:

```
USE master;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.sys.databases d WHERE d.name = 'TestPerms_20160921')
BEGIN
    DROP DATABASE TestPerms_20160921;
END;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestPerms_20160921;
GO
USE TestPerms_20160921;
GO
```

Create a table, and a stored proc:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TestID INT NOT NULL
);
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestProc') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
END
GO
```

Create a test user, and a test role:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.database_principals dp 
    WHERE dp.name = 'TestU'
    )
BEGIN
    DROP USER TestU;
END
CREATE USER TestU WITHOUT LOGIN;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.database_principals dp 
    WHERE dp.name = 'dbtestrole'
    )
BEGIN
    DROP ROLE dbtestrole;
END
CREATE ROLE dbtestrole;

ALTER ROLE dbtestrole ADD MEMBER TestU;
```

Grant `SELECT` and `EXECUTE` to the test objects:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Test TO dbtestrole;
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TestProc TO dbtestrole;
```

Impersonate the user so we can see the effect of the `GRANT` statements above:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestU';

/* column names and types **are** visible */    
SELECT s.name
    , t.name
    , c.name
    , ty.name
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
WHERE s.name = 'dbo'
    AND t.name = 'Test'
ORDER BY s.name
    , t.name
    , c.name;

/* access to view the definition is denied */
EXEC sys.sp_helptext @objname = 'dbo.TestProc', @columnname = NULL;

/* we can run the proc! */
EXEC dbo.TestProc;

REVERT;
```

`DENY VIEW DEFINITION` on the table, and test again:

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.Test TO dbtestrole;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestU';

/* no rows returned as we can no longer view the table definition */
SELECT s.name
    , t.name
    , c.name
    , ty.name
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
WHERE s.name = 'dbo'
    AND t.name = 'Test'
ORDER BY s.name
    , t.name
    , c.name;

/* we can still run the proc */
EXEC dbo.TestProc;

/* we can still see the content of the table */
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test;

REVERT;
```

Cleanup:

```
USE master;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.sys.databases d WHERE d.name = 'TestPerms_20160921')
DROP DATABASE TestPerms_20160921;
```